# Linq like or other construction

Tags: c#, sql, linq, oracle, sql-like

I have DB oracle in my solution.
I want to have some results in this query.
Query example:

```
select * from doctor where doctor.name like '%IVANOV_A%';
```

But if i do it at LINQ i cannot get any result.

```
from p in repository.Doctor.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(name))
select p;
```

Where 'name' is variable of string parameter.

Web layout  request next string: "Ivanov a" or "A Ivanov"

But i suggest for user choose you pattetn for query.

How i can to get "patient by name" if name consist of "First name" and "Last name" but user doesn't know your doctor's full name?

PS: I forced to use next sql:

```
select * 
from doctor
where doctor.name like '%Ivano%' and doctor.name like '%Serg%';
```

Comment: Do you get results if you change it like this? `from p in repository.Doctor.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) select p;`

Comment: I was thinking you can guess. In my code 'name.ToLower()' it is written. The problem is not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction("WebDataModel", "String_Like")]
public static bool Like(this string input, string pattern)
{
    /* Turn "off" all regular expression related syntax in
     * the pattern string. */
    pattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);

    /* Replace the SQL LIKE wildcard metacharacters with the
     * equivalent regular expression metacharacters. */
    pattern = pattern.Replace("%", ".*?").Replace("_", ".");

    /* The previous call to Regex.Escape actually turned off
     * too many metacharacters, i.e. those which are recognized by
     * both the regular expression engine and the SQL LIKE
     * statement ([...] and [^...]). Those metacharacters have
     * to be manually unescaped here. */
    pattern = pattern.Replace(@"\[", "[").Replace(@"\]", "]").Replace(@"\^", "^");

    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

[Link - this answer(warning - russian).](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/168634/sql-like-%D0%B2-linq-net)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
repository.Doctor.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name))
```

Both in linq-to-sql and linq-to-entities this is translated to a `LIKE %...%`. You probably don't even need the `ToLower` because the comparison is completely database-side, so the database's collation is used. You'll have to try, but often databases are case-insensitive by default. But you can use the `ToLower` if necessary, it will translate to SQL.

As for the name sequence issue. Whatever search string you get, you can play with trailing and leading spaces to find a match. Let's say the search string is "A B". The matches should be ((like "%A %" and like "% B%") or (like "% A%") and like "%B %"). (Wathc the space characters!). You can work this out by splitting the string at the space character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may work (didn't test it):

```
from p in repository.Doctor.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
select p;
```

Comment: No, men, no. Are you really understood me?